# What are the cons of using Django compared to (ASP.net MVC,NHibernate and Spark View Engine)?

Tags: django, asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine, ndjango

I am new to ASP.net MVC, but I am pretty used to Django. I find ASP.net very dragging to do even small things. Comparing Django to ASP.net MVC with NHibernate and Spark View Engine, am I missing anything in Django that makes ASP.net too good ? Is the performance of ASP.net much better than Django since ASP.net is compiled ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're new to ASP.NET MVC, but happy with Django and you're looking to evaluate ASP.NET MVC on merits alone, then it might be clouding your assessment by throwing another new technology in there like the [Spark View Engine](http://www.sparkviewengine.com/). Something that may be worth trying is using the [NDjango View Engine](http://ndjango.org/index.php?title=NDjango_Home) instead, so that you can use the same view syntax you've been used to and then purely look at ASP.NET MVC as a technology.

If you find then that it's ASP.NET MVC that's slowing you down or getting in your way, but still want to work on .NET, you could always give something like [NancyFx](http://nancyfx.org/) a try which has simplicity built into its core (taking some design cues from the popular [Ruby Sinatra framework](http://www.sinatrarb.com/)) and also has support for both Spark as well as NDjango.

Regarding performance, while it's true that Python is not compiled, just as is the case with Ruby, I can't see it making much of a difference to the end user because networking (and the internet in general) are where the bottlenecks and latency lie which will have absolutely nothing to do with your code being compiled or not. More often than not, it's bad data access strategies or the way you've actually written the code that would slow it down long before the interpreter became an issue.

Hope that helps
Rob

**Full disclosure:** I happen to be a developer on the Spark View Engine and so it may seem counter-intuitive what I'm advising above, but I think it's important not to cloud your evaluation of a new technology with too many variables or moving parts. One thing at a time, and I'm pretty sure in time you'll come to realise that Spark is the best view engine out there anyway ;-P

Answer (score 0):

Very good read: http://drozdyuk.blogspot.com/2009/03/django-and-aspnet-mvc.html

Also consider the above blogpost is more than year old and ASP.NET MVC has come a long way.

Saying that most of the times the discussion comes down to how good are you in a certain language/framework? Like in the blog, it says you need to learn Apache, tools etc. to maintain/deploy your Django applications while in ASP.NET MVC its pretty simple and straightforward.